# Strange Bingbot hits in my website access logs

Tags: htaccess, logs

I'm seeing many hits to my site recently in the access logs and I'm not sure what to do with them. The pages they are trying to reach do not exist and they say they are coming from Bingbot, but I don't think those are bing IP addresses. Any one have any ideas of how I should handle these either via htaccess or reporting it to Bing?

```
66.249.69.1 - - [11/Aug/2016:07:41:23 -0400] "GET /index.php/write-academic-papers-for-money/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10014 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com /bot.html)"
70.208.74.141 - - [11/Aug/2016:07:41:28 -0400] "GET /images/ways.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 188202 "http://tt.tennis- warehouse.com/index.php?threads/nice-mean-pros-on-tour.570480/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12D508 Safari/600.1.4"
40.77.167.6 - - [11/Aug/2016:07:41:30 -0400] "GET /index.php/buy-research-paper-no-plagiarism/gifts-gear.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9866 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0;)"
```

Comment: Only the last line in your example says it is Bing. The first is Google. These are probably due to bad links either on your site or another. It is not uncommon that spam link sites make bad links. Because the first and last are the same, that makes sense. Just let them go. Do not worry about 404 errors for pages that do not exist. That is what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Is there something I can do to prevent any /index.php/XXXXXX requests to my site? My concern is that these links do show up in google if I search for my site AND for example buy-research-paper-no-plagiarism. Basically, I don't have any pages/links on my site that are appended to the file name such as index.php or locations.php for example.

Comment: "The pages they are trying to reach do not exist" - yet the 3 log entries posted all return a 200 OK status, not a 404? "Only the last line in your example says it is Bing" and it looks like a valid Bing IP address as well?

Comment: You are correct - they are showing as 200. Not sure what that means or how to correct it since those pages don't exist. Maybe there's a way I can redirect them to a 404 error? This is an apache site, so I should be able to make any htaccess modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 log records shown all look like legitimate traffic (both the Google and Bing IP addresses appear valid) and as closetnoc has already pointed out, only the last one references the Bingbot.

> The pages they are trying to reach do not exist

But your server is returning a 200 OK status, which is potentially allowing these URLs to be indexed by the search engines. If these URLs returned a 404 Not Found then it wouldn't be such a problem.

It looks like your site has been the target of a XSS-like attack to create spammy links in the SERPs for keywords that are irrelevant to your site.

> Is there something I can do to prevent any /index.php/XXXXXX requests

Yes. The additional `XXXXXX` in the URL after a valid filename is trailing *pathname information* (`PATH_INFO`). The default behaviour on Apache generally allows this additional path info (although it depends on the handler).

However, this can be disabled with the `AcceptPathInfo` directive in your server config or .htaccess file. For example:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

This will result in Apache returning a 404 NOT FOUND error on such requests.

Apache docs...
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

---

Depending on your website URL structure, you could just block any *direct requests* to `index.php`. Something like the following, using mod_rewrite in the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [F]
```

This would need to go *before* any URL routing directives (eg. WordPress).

`THE_REQUEST` contains the initial request header only, so you are still OK to internally rewrite to `index.php` if you are using a front controller (for example).